# Call to POPEN causes hang inside thread

Tags: python, multithreading, popen

My code seems to hang on this popen call

```
command = "ls"
commandList = shlex.split(command)
print("Executing " + command +"\n")
print(commandList)
output = "#" * 10 + "\n" + server.name + "\n\n"
process = subprocess.Popen(
    command,
    shell=True,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = process.communicate()[0]
#scriptRunner.threadComplete(output)
return output
```

The code is in the `executeScriptOverSSH` method on the `SshWorker`

```
class WorkerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, pathToScript, server, runner):
        super(WorkerThread, self).__init__()
        self.scriptRunner = runner
        self.server = server
        self.pathToScript = pathToScript
        self.sshWorker = SshWorker.SshWorker()

    def run(self):
        print('Thread Starting')
        output = self.sshWorker.executeScriptOverSSH(
            self.server, 
            self.pathToScript)
        print('Thread Finishing!')
        self.scriptRunner.threadComplete(output)`
```

The threads never get past the call to `Popen` -- I've checked by using print statements there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run the below code and it runs correctly. You mentioned that "check_output barfs if the return code is non zero", check out the [check_output docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) it raises a [CalledProcessError](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CalledProcessError) exception which you can catch and contains all the error details in a nice structure.

```
import threading, subprocess, random, time, pprint
from subprocess import check_output

class WorkerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, user, host, script, runner):
        super(WorkerThread, self).__init__()
        self.user = user
        self.host = host
        self.script = script
        self.runner = runner

    def run(self):
        cmd = "ssh {user}@{host} 'bash -s' < {script}".format(**self.__dict__)
        self.runner.complete(check_output(cmd, shell=True))

class Runner(object):
    def complete(self, output):
        print 'output:\n', output

WorkerThread('marwan', 'homebox', 'local_script.sh', Runner()).start()
```

The code above follows the same structure you posted in your question. But I don't recommend you take this approach here are some suggestions:

- From the WorkerThread you call runner, I don't know the details of runner but when doing multi-threaded programming the most robust thread-safe option is to communicate using a [Queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html#queue-objects).
- There are a number of excellent libraries that do what you are doing here hand. They are well tested and do it cleanly. [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) is excellent and [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org) is really great too.

**simple fabric remote run example**

```
from fabric.api import run

def anonymous():
    run("uname -a")
```

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't more clear. This is ok except check_output barfs if the return code is non zero. The actual command I tried to run is ssh root@MachineB 'bash -s' < local_script.sh where I try to run a bash script on a remote machine through ssh.